# adding n to variable name in R

Tags: r, variables, naming

I am trying to keep track of my iterations so I can compare the outcomes for model selection.

My code currently looks like this:

```
library(depmixS4) 
n <- 2
for (i in 1:11) {
  model <- mix(list(DCRF$Specify_SaO2 ~ 1, DCRF$Haematocrit_1 ~ 1, DCRF$Glasgow_Coma_Score ~ 1),
               family = list(gaussian("identity"),  # For every corresponding 
                             gaussian("identity"),  #    indicator a family of distribution 
                             multinomial("identity")), #    should be indicated in the list.
               data = DCRF,        
               nstates = n,        # This is the number of classes
               initdata = DCRF     
  )
  fit.mod <- fit(model)   
  
  print(fit.mod)

  n <- n + 1
}
```

Ideally, I would like variable `fit.mod` to keep track of the corresponding value of `n`, by writing to a new variable `fit.modn`
So I want to end up with the new variables `fit.mod2`, `fit.mod3`, `fit.mod4`, and so on.

Comment: You could either use named lists  (probably better) or the `assign` function.

Comment: [Use lists!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207)

Answer (score 1):

You can store each iteration of the model in a `list`.

```
library(depmixS4) 

fit.mods <- list() # we initialize an empty list

for (i in 1:11) {

  model <- mix(list(DCRF$Specify_SaO2 ~ 1, DCRF$Haematocrit_1 ~ 1, DCRF$Glasgow_Coma_Score ~ 1),
               family = list(gaussian("identity"),  # For every corresponding 
                             gaussian("identity"),  #    indicator a family of distribution 
                             multinomial("identity")), #    should be indicated in the list.
               data = DCRF,        
               nstates = i + 1,        # This is the number of classes
               initdata = DCRF     
  )
  fit.mods[i] <- fit(model)   # using bracket indexing we write each fitted model to a separate list entry
  
  print(fit.mod)
}
```

You can name the list entries like this:

```
names(fit.mods) <- paste0("fit.mod", 1:11)
```

Alternatively you could use `lapply()` or `purrr::map()` instead of a `for` loop. They already produce (named) lists as outputs and also you don't need to initialize the `list`.

```
fit.mods <- lapply(1:11, function(x) {
  model <-
    mix(
      list(
        DCRF$Specify_SaO2 ~ 1,
        DCRF$Haematocrit_1 ~ 1,
        DCRF$Glasgow_Coma_Score ~ 1
      ),
      family = list(
        gaussian("identity"),
        # For every corresponding
        gaussian("identity"),
        #    indicator a family of distribution
        multinomial("identity")
      ),
      #    should be indicated in the list.
      data = DCRF,
      nstates = x + 1,
      # This is the number of classes
      initdata = DCRF
    )
  fit(model)
})
```

Also the [tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/) provide an explicit framework for iterating through variations of the same model. It looks like `depmixS4` is currently not supported, but it is worth taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using named lists of objects:

```
results <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
  results[[paste0("iteration_", i)]] <- data.frame(some_value = 1:i)
}
```

The list `results` is now:

> ```
> $iteration_1
>   some_value
> 1          1
>
> $iteration_2
>   some_value
> 1          1
> 2          2
>
> $iteration_3
>   some_value
> 1          1
> 2          2
> 3          3
> ```